# Is there a list of endangered writing systems?

Tags: writing, endangered-languages

Is there a list of endangered writing systems? I couldn't find any.

Comment: Hi, welcome to LL.SE. Could you be more explicit about how your question is related to learning languages?

Comment: It isn't that related but I couldn't find any other stack exchanges which were better.

Comment: "Endangered" in terms of number of users? The difficulty here is that there's no real difference between "native/L1 speakers" and "secondary/L2 speakers" for a writing system, and that's an important difference when talking about endangered _languages_. But the number of people who use a particular writing system should be measurable.

Comment: for endangered i meant where "L1+L2 < people needed for it to not be endangered"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something approximating such a list is [this map](https://www.endangeredalphabets.net/). It includes traditional writing as well as modern inventions that don't have a long historical tradition. The Klingon alphabet (and various conlang scripts) are not included, nor (apparently) are extinct systems like Egyptian hieroglyphics, but it does include Coptic since there are still people who use the writing system.